# Django Model Form: show query form and handle post request for OneToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am a newbie to Django and could not find similar questions after searching on google/SO.

I've a model named Questions, which has multiple(2-4) choices and defined as below:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
class Choice(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=256)     
  is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Of the multiple choices only one is correct.

What I want to do: In just one page, user could submit a question together with multiple choices, here is a draft of UI:

[image]

My first question: I've defined ModelForm but don't know how to add "choices" field to QuestionForm:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
  description = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
  class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ['name', 'description']

class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
  is_correct = forms.BooleanField()
  class Meta:
    model = Choice
    fields = ['name', 'is_correct']
```

Is it possible to use ModelForm the render the above HTML page besides writing it manually?

My second question: If use clicks "Submit" button, I use AJAX to send json data to backend server, here is an example of form data:

```
name:question1
choices[][name]:choice1
choices[][is_correct]:1
choices[][name]:choice2
choices[][is_correct]:0
```

And this is my code handling the request:

```
form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
  question = form.save()
```

How to parse choices from the request? 
How could I parse data of multiple choices part from the POST request?

Again, I'm a newbie to Django and any answers/suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To create forms for models which have a OneToMany relation I would recommend you to use Django's inline formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

It's a really simple and elegant way to create forms for related models.

To parse the choices, the user entered you could just override the `clean` method of your form. In this the user content is usually checked and prepared for storing it to the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

So cleaning could look like this:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(QuestionForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data['choice_name'].startswith('Something'):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Choice names cannot start with 'Something'!"
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You models seems to be correct, in order to be able to add mutiple choices in your template you need a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/). In addition you can put a formset and a form inside the same html form in a template and have them be validated individually. Each one only cares about the POST data relevant to them. Something like:

**template.html**

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ choices_formset.management_form }} <!-- used by django to manage formsets -->
    {{ question_form.as_p }}
    {% for form in choices_formset %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def new_question(request):
    ChoicesFormset = formset_factory(ChoicesForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        choices_formset = ChoicesFormset(request.POST)
        if question_form.is_valid():
            question = Question(**question_form.cleaned_data)
            if choices_formset.is_valid():
                question.save()
                new_choice_list = list()
                append_choice = new_choice_list.append
                for form in choices_formset:
                    form.cleaned_data.update({'question': question})
                    append_choice(Choice(**form.cleaned_data))
                try:
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        Choice.objects.bulk_create(new_choice_list)
                except IntegrityError as e:
                    raise IntegrityError
        return redirect(reverse('question-detail-view', kwargs={'id': question.id}))

def question_detail(request, id):
    question_list = Question.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'question_detail.html', {'question_list': question_list})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^question/$', new_question, name='new-question-view'),
url(r'^question/(?P<id>\d+)/$', question_detail, name='question-detail-view'),
```

If you want to use rather [Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) submission rather than django form sumbission **check this** [tutoriel](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/).

Comment: Yes, dude, it solved my 2nd question, now I was able to parse choices from POST request and save to db, and a typo in your answer(EventTerminaltype -> Choice); For question 1st, your answer did work, but the HTML elements is not what I expected(such as extra CSS class 'form-group', 'from-contrl', extra attributes 'placeholder'...), so I wrote the HTML forms manually.  Thanks!

Comment: I just used the shortest way, to make it easier to be read, but you can of course write forms explicitly. Concerning Ajax submission it's a whole big tutorial. you can make it as separate question, or you can check the 2 links I added to my post about django form ajax submission and the typo is fixed.