# Django saving models by JS rather than form submissions?

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a contract job for editing a Django application, and Django is not my main framework to use, so I have a question regarding models in it.

The application I am editing has a form that each user can submit, and every single model in the application is edited directly through the form.

From this perspective, it seems every model is directly a form object, I do not see any model fields that I could use for custom variables. Meaning instead of a "string" that I could edit with JS, I only see a TextField where the only way it could be edited is by including it on a form directly.

If I wanted to have some models that were custom variables, meaning I controlled them entirely through JS rather than form submissions, how would I do that in Django?

I know I could, for example, have some "hidden" form objects that I manipulated with JS. But this solution sounds kind of hacky. Is there an intended way that I could go about this?

Thanks!

(**Edit**: It seems most responses do not know what I am referring to. Basically I want to allow the client to perform some special sorting functions etc, in which case I will need a few additional lists of data. But I do not want these to be visible to the user, and they will be altered exclusively by js.

Regarding the response of SColvin, I understand that the models are a representation of the database, but from how the application I am working on is designed, it looks as if the only way the models are being used is strictly through forms.

For example, every "string" is a "TextField", and lets say we made a string called "myField", the exclusive use of this field would be to use it in templates with the syntax {{ form.myField|attr:"rows:4" }}.

There are absolutely no use of this model outside of the forms. Every place you see it in the application, there is a form object. This is why I was under the impression that is the primary way to edit the data found in the models.

I did the Django tutorial prior to accepting this project but do not remember seeing any way to submit changes to models outside of the forms.

**So more specifically what I would like to do in this case**: Let's say I wanted to add a string to my models file, and this string will NOT be included/edited on the form. It will be invisible to the user. It will be modified browser-side by some .js functions, and I would like it to be saved along when submitting the rest of the form. What would be the intended method for going about doing this?

If anyone could please guide me to documentation or examples on how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated! )

(**Edit2**: No responses ever since the first edit? Not sure if this post is not appearing for anyone else. Still looking for an answer!)

Comment: perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "custom variables" in javascript? I also think you've got confused about "models" (eg. a database table) and fields (eg. a single column in a database table).

Comment: Check the answer here, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34371264/5658350

Comment: I added some more information that will (hopefully) better describe my question!

Answer (score 0):

There is some terminology confusion here, as SColvin points out; it's really not clear what you mean by "custom variables", and how those relates to models.

However your main confusion seems to be around forms. There is absolutely no requirement to use them: they are just one method of updating models. It is always possible to edit the models directly in code, and the data from that can of course come from Javascript if you want. The tutorial has good coverage of how to update a model from code without using a form.

If you're doing a lot of work via JS though, you probably want to look into the Django Rest Framework, which simplifies the process of converting Django model data to and from JSON to use in your client-side code. Again though DRF isn't doing anything you couldn't do manually in your own code, all without the use of forms.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I added some more information that will (hopefully) better describe my question!

You mention it is in the tutorial for how to update it without a form? I do not recall that during the official tutorial (if that is what you mean). I would greatly appreciate this if you could guide me to this!

Thanks!